# How do I create a textarea countdown with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown

I'm working on this survey form, and I'm trying to code a comment area that has a character limit of 500. From what I've seen, I'm doing everything "right", but clearly I must be overlooking something.

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4c0mxuug/).

**HTML**

```
<span class="char-remain">500 Characters remaining</span>
<textarea class="comment" rows="10" cols="50" maxlength="500">Enter Text Here</textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
comment = $(".comment");             

comment.on("keyup change", function(){

   charCount = $(this).text().length;
   charRemain = 500 - charCount;

   $(this).prev("span").text("(" + charRemain + ")");

   alert(charRemain + "Characters Remaining");

});
```

The alert is there really for me to see if it's working or triggering at all, which it isn't. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error in the first line.

```
$(document).ready(function {
```

Only change to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

As you're trying to get the length of the comment field, you need to use the `.val()` function. It's an equivalent to `.value` in plain JavaScript.

However, you can optimize your code by using the next:

```
var maxlength = parseInt(comment.attr("maxlength"), 10);
```

The code above will store the comment's field `maxlength`. So you might try with:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var comment = $(".comment");
  var maxlength = parseInt(comment.attr("maxlength"), 10);

  comment.on("keyup keypress change", function() {
    charCount = $(this).val().length;
    charRemain = maxlength - charCount;
    //$(this).prev().prev("span").text(charRemain + " Characters remaining");
    $(".char-remain").text(charRemain + " Characters remaining");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="char-remain">500 Characters remaining</span>
<br />
<textarea class="comment" rows="10" cols="50" maxlength="500">Enter Text Here</textarea>
```

As suggested @TiesonT. in the comments, you could easily get the span content by using:

```
$(".char-remain").text(charRemain + " Characters remaining");
```

In this context you don't need to worry about tags between the comment field and the span content.

**Updated:**

You might bind with the `keypress` event to get the current length while the user is pressing a key.

```
comment.on("keyup keypress change", function() {
```

Comment: Fardy Jhonston Be - Ok, so I see this works on my jsFiddle, but it wasn't working on my main code. I did a quick look-over, and I left out something from my original code. There is a </br> after my <span> before the <textarea>. For some reason this seems to be keeping my code from working, as it stops working on the jsFiddle when I add it there. How do I get around that?

Comment: You might try with: $(this).prev().prev("span").text(charRemain + " Characters remaining"); Check my answer, please.

Comment: Rather than `prev().prev('span')`, just use `$('.char-remain')` to get the "characters remaining" element.

Comment: Btw, in HTML </br> doesn't exist. The correct sintax is <br> for HTML4 and HTML5; or <br /> in XHTML or HTML5+XML.

Comment: @TiesonT. Agree, this is the fast and proper way, in this case.

Comment: If there will be more than one comment field, you can also use `.siblings()`: https://jsfiddle.net/qhos5gxw/2/

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez - I got it to work with prevAll(), although I guess siblings could have worked. There will be more than one comment box eventually, I was just getting the code working for one before I scaled up. The code appears to be working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You made two errors here.

Your document ready did not have the right syntax secondly, getting the value from a text area is not `text()` but it is `val()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  comment = $(".comment");

  comment.on("keyup change", function() {

    charCount = $(this).val().length;
    charRemain = 500 - charCount;

    $(this).prev("span").text("(" + charRemain + ")");

    alert(charRemain + "Characters Remaining");

  });
});
```